# python list group by first character

Tags: python, python-itertools, divide

```
list1=['hello','hope','hate','hack','bit','basket','code','come','chess']
```

What I need is:

```
list2=[['hello','hope','hate','hack'],['bit','basket'],['code','come','chess']]
```

If the first character is the same and is the same group, then sublist it.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What if the word 'hack' was at the end of the list?

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> list1 = ['hello','hope','hate','hack','bit','basket','code','come','chess']
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(list1, key=lambda x: x[0])]
[['hello', 'hope', 'hate', 'hack'], ['bit', 'basket'], ['code', 'come', 'chess']]
```

Comment: @Lee_Prison Itertools is very cool :). Give it a look if you want; I linked the docs :)

Comment: as an alternative to lambda, you may want to use `operator.itemgetter(0)`

Comment: This solution only works if the list is sorted.  You could sort the list first, but performance would not be ideal.  Is there another python lib that is more versatile?

Comment: @josiah maybe see my answer on that

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on TerryA's answer:

To create a dict with the first letter as key and the matching elements as value, you can do

```
>>> list1=['hello','hope','hate','hack','bit','basket','code','come','chess', 'archetype', 'cheese']
... mydict={}
... for k, g in groupby(list1, key=lambda x: x[0]):
...    if k in mydict:
...        mydict[k] += g
...    else:
...        mydict[k]=list(g)
... print(mydict)
{'h': ['hello', 'hope', 'hate', 'hack'], 'b': ['bit', 'basket'], 'a': ['archetype'], 'c': ['code', 'come', 'chess', 'cheese']}
```

This also works if list1 is not sorted (as shown) and it can, of course, also be converted to a list of lists again with

```
>>> [v for k, v in mydict.items()]
[['hello', 'hope', 'hate', 'hack'], ['bit', 'basket'], ['archetype'], ['code', 'come', 'chess', 'cheese']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [partition_by](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/seqs.html#partition_by) function from my [funcy](https://github.com/Suor/funcy) library:

```
from funcy import partition_by
list2 = partition_by(0, list1)
```

Note that this will only work if `list1` is already sorted, as with `itertools.groupby`. If `list1` is unsorted than sorting it and then partitioning would be inefficient, the better way would be to use [group_by](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/seqs.html#group_by) function:

```
from funcy import group_by
list2 = group_by(0, list1).values()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.7+ (i.e. a version where dictionaries maintain insertion order) you could simply use a dict of lists keyed by the first character to group the words. This works with both sorted and unsorted input:

```
list1 = ['hello', 'hope', 'hate', 'bit', 'basket', 'code', 'come', 'chess', 'hack']
d = {}

for word in list1:
    d.setdefault(word[0], []).append(word)
list2 = list(d.values())
print(list2)
# [['hello', 'hope', 'hate', 'hack'], ['bit', 'basket'], ['code', 'come', 'chess']]
```