# How to group elements effectively in a huge list by their first character in python

Tags: python

I am following the answer of the following stackoverflow question to accomplish my task as follows. [python list group by first character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876130/python-list-group-by-first-character)

```
import json
from itertools import groupby

#Load data
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    concepts = []
    for concept in f:
        concepts.append(concept.strip())

print(len(concepts))

concepts_list = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(concepts, key=lambda x: x[0])]

concepts_dict = {}
for item in concepts_list:
    concepts_dict[item[0][0]] = item

with open("concepts_preprocessed_dictionary.txt", "w") as fw:
    fw.write(json.dumps(concepts_dict))
```

However, I am wondering why this code is not working when there are huge number of concepts in the list (aproximately 13,000,000 concepts). Surprisingly the program executes in seconds and when I check the dictionary it contains wrong results (in other words the dictionary file is only 1KB in size and contain mostly one or two elements per grouped lists).

Unfortunately, I am not in a position to share my concept list as it violates some privacy issues.

But I found a long word list in the following github page: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt

However, unlike the above mentioned dataset my current dataset is only àlphabetically ordered by first character` (i.e. as follows)

**My dataset:** Only first letter is `m`, but the remaining words are not albetically ordered

- methods
- machine learning
- mic

**Dataset I have mentioned**: Nicely ordered based on characters

- machine learning
- methods
- mic

Please let me know if there is any further details needed.

Comment: Doesn't `groupby` require the list be sorted?

Comment: Yes @roganjosh. You need to sort the list alphabetically.

Comment: Hmm, the example word list looks reasonably sorted actually. I doubt it just packs in its work but instead would produce disparate groups if the list wasn't sorted. I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: My next suspicion lies in `concepts_dict[item[0][0]] = item` overwriting items in the dictionary. Really, it would have been helpful to demonstrate the issue without dependencies on external files.

Comment: @roganjosh it doesn't *require* it. Often, you want `groupby` *without* sorted data, and if you are going to sort it, you might actually just want a `defaultdict(list)`

Comment: It will be better if you be more specific about wrong results

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga was already writing my comment talking myself out of it and thinking along the lines of `defaultdict` :)

Comment: @DanielMesejo I mentioned few details about the wrong results :)

Comment: Are you really sure that your list is sorted?

Comment: So your list of words looks like `['hello','hope','hate','hack','bit','basket'...]` and from that you want `[['hello','hope','hate','hack'],['bit','basket'],...]`?

Comment: Add this line `concepts = sorted(concepts, key=lambda x: x[0])` before the groupby a check what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really *need* to use `groupby` to do this.

Consider your linked example:

```
list1=['hello','hope','hate','hack','bit','basket','code','come','chess']
```

You can create the groups described with a native Python dict:

```
groups={}
for word in list1:
    groups.setdefault(word[0],[]).append(word)

>>> groups
{'h': ['hello', 'hope', 'hate', 'hack'], 'b': ['bit', 'basket'], 'c': ['code', 'come', 'chess']}
```

Or, with `defaultdict` if your prefer:

```
from collections import defaultdict 
groups=defaultdict(list)    
for word in list1:
    groups[word[0]].append(word)

>>> groups
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'h': ['hello', 'hope', 'hate', 'hack'], 'b': ['bit', 'basket'], 'c': ['code', 'come', 'chess']})
```

Both of these methods will work with completely unsorted data and gather the words based on the first letter. You are then free to use the values of that dict to make a list of lists if desired:

```
>>> sorted(groups.values(), key=lambda s: s[0])
[['bit', 'basket'], ['code', 'come', 'chess'], ['hello', 'hope', 'hate', 'hack']]
```

Now if you *still* want to use `groupby` for some reason, you would likely do something like this:

```
groups={}
for k,v in groupby(list1, key=lambda s: s[0]):
    groups.setdefault(k,[]).extend(v)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I am currently running your code on my dataset. I will mark your answer as correct if that works :)